# Use sql queries in php to display a report in a web applicaiton

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sum, union

I am developing a web application. I am using sql server and php. I've to make selection of some selected columns from different tables of the database and display it on the web in a table format. Also it should indicate the sum of one of the columns after selection(It's a users monthly report and the points the user has scored at the end of the month. So it should display the sum  of the points).

```
<?php

$serverName = "";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "...", "UID" =>"...", "PWD"=>"..." );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}

$sql = "(Select Ad.[Act], Ad.[Units], Ad_Acts.[Name] from Ad JOIN Ad_Act ON Ad.ActID = Ad_Act.ActAttend)
        Union ALL(Select Citi.[Act2], Citi.[Units2], Citi_act.[Name] from Citi JOIN Citi_Acts ON Citi.ActID2 = Citi_Act.ActAttend2)
         Union ALL(Select ComOut.[Act3], ComOut.[Units3], ComOut_Act.[Name] from ComOut JOIN ComOut_Act ON ComOut.ActID3 = ComOut_Act.ActAttend3)
         Union ALL(Select ReSchAct.[Act4], ReSchAct.[Units4], ReSch_Act.[Name] from ReSchAct JOIN ReSch_Act ON ReSchAct.ActID4 = ReSch_Act.ActAttend4)
          Union ALL(Select TeEd.[Act5], TeEd.[Units5], TeEd_Act.[Name] from TeEd JOIN TeEd_Act ON TeEd.ActID5 = TeEd_Act.ActAttend5)"


;

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
if($stmt === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
 echo $row['Act']. ",".$row['Units']. "," .$row['Name']. "<br></br>";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

 ?>
```

The above code is working. I just want help with the code to display the whole thing in a table and display the sum of Units at the end.
Thanks!

Comment: We do not have your data to try that code.  So add to this question the current output you have.  Hint, to show data as a table, look at `<table>`.  Then you can loop on your results and echo `<tr>` and `<td>` elements to fill it.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Queries indicate a suboptimal database design. One should not separate similar structured data into separate tables: *Ad, Citi, ComOut, ReSchAct, TeEd* should all be stored in one table and their *_Act* tables in a second table, each with an indicator column for category. So you maintain 2 tables and not 10!

Comment: I know right! But the user wanted a nav bar. So I had to create different tables and display 10 different navbars!
The 5 tables are five different types of forms which take the user input. So the web app will be having 10 nav bars so the user just has to click on each and enter their activity.

Comment: I don't see how that user request changes the database schema. All forms or navbars can point to same table on different `WHERE` conditions of that indicator category column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your output comes back with 3 fields, `Act, Units, and Name`, then you could get your output with the bottom section of the below snippet.  If that is not the case, then you are probably running into the issue that your UNION is combining fields with different aliases, which should be solved by the changes I made to your select statement..

```
<?php
// .......

$sql = "(Select Ad.[Act] 'Act', Ad.[Units] 'Units', Ad_Acts.[Name] from Ad JOIN Ad_Act ON Ad.ActID = Ad_Act.ActAttend)
        Union ALL(Select Citi.[Act2] 'Act', Citi.[Units2] 'Units', Citi_act.[Name] from Citi JOIN Citi_Acts ON Citi.ActID2 = Citi_Act.ActAttend2)
         Union ALL(Select ComOut.[Act3] 'Act', ComOut.[Units3] 'Units', ComOut_Act.[Name] from ComOut JOIN ComOut_Act ON ComOut.ActID3 = ComOut_Act.ActAttend3)
         Union ALL(Select ReSchAct.[Act4] 'Act', ReSchAct.[Units4] 'Units', ReSch_Act.[Name] from ReSchAct JOIN ReSch_Act ON ReSchAct.ActID4 = ReSch_Act.ActAttend4)
          Union ALL(Select TeEd.[Act5] 'Act', TeEd.[Units5] 'Units', TeEd_Act.[Name] from TeEd JOIN TeEd_Act ON TeEd.ActID5 = TeEd_Act.ActAttend5)";

//  ........

$totalUnits = 0;
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Act</th>
        <th>Units</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
<?php while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Act']</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Units']</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Name']</td>
    </tr>
    <?php $totalUnits = $totalUnits + intval($row['Units']); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total Units: </td>
        <td><?php echo $totalUnits; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey, the code is working but it is not diplaying the sum of the column(Units).

Comment: I made a change to the `<?php $totalUnits = $totalUnits + intval($row['Units']); ?>` line that should solve 2 of the possible problems.